# How to create a list or every permutation in a group of objects N-deep

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a tuple of Action objects

I want to create a list of every possible permutation of the Action objects N deep.

i.e. if I have the actions Eat, Sleep, Drink, and N = 2

the list would be

```
[[Eat, Eat],
 [Eat, Sleep],
 [Eat, Drink],
 [Sleep, Eat],
 [Sleep, Sleep],
 [Sleep, Drink],
 [Drink, Eat],
 [Drink, Sleep],
 [Drink, Drink]]
```

Now, I have a much larger list than three Actions, and N will probably be 3 or more.

How would I do this in Python 2.7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you want the [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of a list with itself. Use [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html):

```
>>> import itertools, pprint
>>> mylist = ["Eat","Sleep","Drink"]
>>> my_combination = list(itertools.product(mylist, repeat = 2))
>>> pprint.pprint (my_combination)
[('Eat', 'Eat'),
 ('Eat', 'Sleep'),
 ('Eat', 'Drink'),
 ('Sleep', 'Eat'),
 ('Sleep', 'Sleep'),
 ('Sleep', 'Drink'),
 ('Drink', 'Eat'),
 ('Drink', 'Sleep'),
 ('Drink', 'Drink')]
```

The optional `repeat` argument controls how "deep" your list is.

Beware that the size of the list grows exponentially with the depth `N`. Don't materialise the whole list at once - instead, use one element at a time.

```
# Don't do this - will crash Python with out-of-memory error
list(itertools.product(my_list, repeat = 100000))

# Iterate over the list instead
for one_combination in itertools.product(my_list, repeat = 100000):
    print (one_combination)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect. Trying it out now.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> actions='eat','sleep','drink'
>>> mylist=[]
>>> [mylist.append(list(i)) for i in list(itertools.product(actions,repeat=2))]
[None,None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
>>> mylist
[['eat', 'eat'], ['eat', 'sleep'], ['eat', 'drink'], ['sleep', 'eat'], ['sleep', 'sleep'],   ['sleep', 'drink'], ['drink', 'eat'], ['drink', 'sleep'], ['drink', 'drink']]
```

Comment: You would achieve the same effect with `mylist = [i for i in itertools.product(...)]`. No need to call `list.append()` in a list comprehension! Addtionally, this works for small lists and small `N`, but for large lists and large `N`, this will try to materialise the entire list at once. Since the full list won't fit in memory, you'll crash Python. (See my answer above.)